# replacing l_ with r_ without removing l_ in ball_GEO etc

Tags: replace

So, my problem is that I am doing an if statement, like this:

```
# get the opposit controler: 
for item in list: 
    if "l_" in item: 
        item.replace("l_", "r_")
```

This works, BUT for items like `l_ball_CTL` it replaces both "l_" so, the item name becomes `r_balr_CTL`.

How can I fix it to replace only the first two characters?

cheers.

Comment: Could You be more specific, at least what language are You talking about? Looks like python.

Answer (score 1):

If it's Python, I'd say:

```
for index, item in list:
    if item.startswith("l_"):
        list[index] = "r_" + item[2:]
```